Understanding an Example of Integral Convergence that is not Local from Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures
In Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures, Example 3.3 on page 24 discusses the failure of a local limit theorem under specific conditions. The example is as follows:

Let $P = \mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $S = [0, 1]$. Define the sequence of functions $f_n$ as
$$
f_n(x) = n^2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1} (k n^{-1}, k n^{-1} + n^{-3})},
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$. With respect to $\mu$, the measure $P_n$ has density $f_n$, i.e.,
$$
dP_n = f_n \, d\mu.
$$
It is shown in the book that $P_n \to P$ weakly (convergence in the sense of integral laws). However, the local limit theorem fails because $f_n(x)$ does not converge to 1 for any $x$.
In the book, it is stated that
$$
\lvert P_n[0, x] - x \rvert \leq \frac{1}{n}.
$$
I am struggling to understand why this bound holds. Here are the key points I think are relevant:

$f_n(x)$ is nonzero only on the intervals $(k n^{-1}, k n^{-1} + n^{-3})$, where $k = 0, 1, \dots, n-1$.
Each interval has length $n^{-3}$, and the total length of all intervals is $n^{-2}$.
On each interval, $f_n(x) = n^2$, and the measure contribution from one interval is approximately $n^{-1}$.

Could someone explain step by step why the bound
$$
\lvert P_n[0, x] - x \rvert \leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
holds, and how to calculate $P_n[0, x]$ explicitly in this setup?

Context
The main goal of this example is to demonstrate that weak convergence does not imply a local limit theorem. While I understand the broader argument, I am stuck on this particular technical detail regarding the bound.
Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Let $n\in\mathbb N^*$ and $x\in[0,1]$. Let $k^*=\lfloor nx\rfloor$, that is the unique integer such that $\frac{k^*}{n}\le x<\frac{k^*+1}{n}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
P_n([0,x])&=\int_0^11_{\{u\le x\}}f_n(u)\,du\\
&=n^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{\frac kn}^{\frac kn+\frac{1}{n^3}}1_{\{u\le x\}}\,du\\
&=n^2\sum_{k=0}^{k^*-1}\int_{\frac kn}^{\frac kn+\frac{1}{n^3}}1\,du+n^2\int_{\frac{k^*}{n}}^{\frac{k^*}{n}+\frac{1}{n^3}}1_{\{u\le x\}}\,du\\
&=n^2\frac{k^*-1}{n^3}+n^2\left(\min\left(\frac{k^*}{n}+\frac{1}{n^3},x\right)-\frac{k^*}{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{k^*-1}{n}+n^2\min\left(\frac{1}{n^3},x-\frac{k^*}{n}\right)\\
&=\min\left(\frac{k^*-1}{n}+n^2\left(x-\frac{k^*}{n}\right),\frac{k^*}{n}\right).
\end{align}
$$
We deduce that $P_n([0,x])\in\left[\frac{k^*-1}{n},\frac{k^*}{n}\right]\subset\left[x-\frac1n,x\right]$, hence
$$
0\le x-P_n([0,x])\le\frac 1n.
$$
